# Talend - Insert 'NULL' into a Database Column which type is 'NUMBER'

Tags: java, sql, database, talend

I want to read values (integers) from a CSV file, and insert them into a Database Table.
However, for a certain column of the table, if the values received from the CSV file don't belong to an interval, the value to write in the Database should be `NULL`.

For example  in my Java App, I do :  `insert.setNull(3, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);` in that cases.

But how can I do this in `Talend`, if the column type is 'NUMBER' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a tMap component between yout tFileInput and database output instances to carry this simple transformation. Inside theis component, on the bottom right pane (the output schema) select the checkbox to let your field be nullable. Be careful, since fields coming from CSV are not nullable by default.

[image]

Finally, on the upper right pane (output transformation), on the target field (the one you forced to be nullable) write a ternary expression. For example:

(assuming your incoming connection is called `input_row`)

```
(input_row.field >= 0 && input_row.field <= 3) ? <value to write if inside interval> : null
```

What I want to say is that if the field is nullable on both Talend side and on the target DB table, the boring java `null` is your friend.

Comment: You can if the Integer field is nullable. Are you sure the proper select box for that field is checked? I've added a screenshot to my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I think the problem is in the Database Table I'm using, that doesn't accept NULL values in that column. In another table, that's working. Thanks :)

Comment: And is something wrong with this ifElse clause: (row1.x== 5 ? 0 : (row1.x == 10 ? 1 : (row1.x== 15 ? 2 : (row1.x== 20 ? 3 : (row1.x== 30 ? 4 : (row1.x == 60 ? 5 : (row1.x== 24 ? 6 : null))))))) ? It is giving me a 'NullPointerExpression' when the field has to be set to NULL...

Comment: This problem is often unrelated (are you sure it's NullPointerExpression and not NullPointerException?). It means you're trying to call a method on x field which is null. Try to put your (very tricky) expression on a user routine and debug from there